# Using Thread with paint java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, switch-statement, event-dispatch-thread

I'm developing a checkers game in Java, and I stumbled on a problem.
What I'm trying to create is that when a checkerpiece is pressed, the available 2 spots in front of it should turn into grey for 2 seconds.

Turn into grey is easy, but when I want it to turn back after 2 seconds using Thread.sleep(2000), I noticed that it first does the rest of the case in this switch before actually sleeping (so it turns the fresh grey squares back to black immediately)

What went wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
switch (bord[ypos][xpos]) {
                case 0:

                    break;
                case 1:

                    break;
                case 2:

                    if (bord[ypos + 1][xpos - 1] == 1) {
                        bord[ypos + 1][xpos - 1] = 4;

                    }
                    if (bord[ypos + 1][xpos + 1] == 1) {
                        bord[ypos + 1][xpos + 1] = 4;

                    }
                    repaint();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                    if (bord[ypos + 1][xpos - 1] == 4) {
                        bord[ypos + 1][xpos - 1] = 1;
                    }
                    if (bord[ypos + 1][xpos + 1] == 4) {
                        bord[ypos + 1][xpos + 1] = 1;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:

                    break;
            }
```

Trying it out with timers(I'm new to these so please don't facepalm too hard)

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package dammen;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author Boyen
 */
public class Board extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    boolean test;
    boolean black = false;
    boolean redpiece = false;
    boolean bluepiece = true;
    Timer timer;
    private int[][] bord = {{0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2},
        {2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0},
        {0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2},
        {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
        {3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0},
        {0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3},
        {3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0}};

    public Board(Dammen parent) {
        addMouseListener(this);
        timer = new Timer(100,taskPerformer);
        timer.setRepeats(false);
    }

    public void start() {
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        Dimension size = getSize();

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                switch (bord[i][j]) {
                    case 0:
                        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        g.setColor(Color.RED);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        g.setColor(Color.gray);
                        break;
                }
                g.fillRect((size.width / 8) * j, (size.height / 8) * i, size.width / 8, size.height / 8);
            }

        }
    }
    int mouseX, mouseY;

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {


        mouseX = e.getX();
        mouseY = e.getY();

        zoekmogelijkespots(mouseX, mouseY);

    }
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
  };

    public void zoekmogelijkespots(int mouseX, int mouseY) {

            Dimension size = getSize();
            System.out.println(mouseX + "," + mouseY);
            int xpos;
            int ypos;
            xpos = (int) (mouseX / (size.width / 8));
            ypos = (int) (mouseY / (size.height / 8));
            System.out.println(ypos + "," + xpos);
            System.out.println(bord[ypos][xpos]);
            switch (bord[ypos][xpos]) {
                case 0:

                    break;
                case 1:

                    break;
                case 2:

                    if (bord[ypos + 1][xpos - 1] == 1) {
                        bord[ypos + 1][xpos - 1] = 4;

                    }
                    if (bord[ypos + 1][xpos + 1] == 1) {
                        bord[ypos + 1][xpos + 1] = 4;

                    }
                    repaint();
                    timer.start();
                    if (bord[ypos + 1][xpos - 1] == 4) {
                        bord[ypos + 1][xpos - 1] = 1;
                    }
                    if (bord[ypos + 1][xpos + 1] == 4) {
                        bord[ypos + 1][xpos + 1] = 1;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:

                    break;
            }


    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your game running on the event thread or another thread?

Comment: @durron597 The Thread.sleep(2000); is the only line written that has anything to do with threads in the whole code, if that's what you wonder (it was suggested by a friend)

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a single shot Swing `Timer`. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: To my understanding timers are only for repetitive tasks? this is on action , I might be wrong though.

Comment: @Boyen: Andrew has answered 1139 swing questions with 3373 up votes. You can trust him regarding swing. BTW, you're asking a question for which he probably earned 2000 up votes, because it's being asked twice every day.

Comment: Did you note how I said 'single shot' Timer?  See [`Timer.setRepeats(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#setRepeats%28boolean%29). ;)  BTW -  You can ignore the `SwingWorker` suggestion - that is overkill.

Comment: @Boyen A Timer can be used to schedule any event to occur at some predefined time in the future, reoccurring or not

Comment: @JBNizet  (Tips hat)  :)

Comment: +1 for having a go at using the `Timer`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a Swing javax.swing.Timer to achieve what you want...

```
if (bord[ypos + 1][xpos - 1] == 1) {
    bord[ypos + 1][xpos - 1] = 4;
}
if (bord[ypos + 1][xpos + 1] == 1) {
    bord[ypos + 1][xpos + 1] = 4;
}
repaint();
Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (bord[ypos + 1][xpos - 1] == 4) {
            bord[ypos + 1][xpos - 1] = 1;
        }
        if (bord[ypos + 1][xpos + 1] == 4) {
            bord[ypos + 1][xpos + 1] = 1;
        }
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Thread.sleep(2000);`, you could do this (note, I have no way to test this):

```
public static class GrayWorker extends SwingWorker<Object, Object> {
    private final int xpos;
    private final int ypos;
    private final int[][] bord;
    public GrayWorker(int[][] bord, int xpos, int ypos) {
        this.bord = bord; this.xpos = xpos; this.ypos = ypos;
    }

    @Override
    public Object doInBackground() {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        if (bord[ypos + 1][xpos - 1] == 4) {
            bord[ypos + 1][xpos - 1] = 1;
        }
        if (bord[ypos + 1][xpos + 1] == 4) {
            bord[ypos + 1][xpos + 1] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your other class, do:

```
GrayWorker worker = new GrayWorker(bord, xpos, ypos);
worker.execute();
```

Comment: +1 for an interesting approach, but javax.swing.Timer would be a simpler solution